# How copy location without measuring unit?

Tags: workflow

I just want to copy the value without unit when hovering over the location field. Is this somehow possible?

If you copy a lot of values, you don't want to delete the unit all the time.

Comment: Switch under Scene properties > Units > Unit System to None

Comment: works like a charm! If you want to write an answer...you will get accept + upvote

Comment: No, thanks ... great it works for you :)